# display banner in full size

Tags: html, css

Why does this banner (which is inside of iFrame) not enlarge to the full size of the div?

My [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vhy82x6w/1/) can be found here, and some of my CSS is below :

```
 width: 300px;
 height: 222px;
 background-size: cover;
```

Comment: because your image is only 200 pixels wide

Comment: @Amit yes but background-size cover should display it in full size of div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
<div class="indexRightBanners">
    <iframe class="banner300x222Iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

With css:

```
.indexRightBanners {
  width: 300px;
  height: 222px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.banner300x222Iframe {
    background-image: url(http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20141123145956/powerpuff/images/4/4e/IaCN7A0NfI4ig3cnoNGD2lADi06s4b2fB8S9nNEVKM4hpJv5qzy3Z3euZWr2Sw5Rj5QwKVMvdj-300x222.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    width: 300px;
    height: 222px;
}
```

-> http://jsfiddle.net/vhy82x6w/3/

The Problem with your code is that your image is only 200px wide as Amit pointed out.

Comment: if there will background image how will there display flash banner?

Comment: I don't know what you want, but afaik there's no html/css solution to scale swf natively.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the content within an iFrame. Including styling. If your content is just a picture, you could just use an img tag with the src attribute set to your url.

If you need the html content, you could try loading it into the div using ajax and jquery. If the url is in the same domain as your page then you could use [Jquery's $.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), if it is in an outside domain, you could use  [This Cross Origin Solution](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/). Once you load the content, you would have full access to it in the DOM for styling.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has the ability to try to stretch things by using percentages.
Try using the following :

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-size: 100%;
```

More information on the CSS percentage properties can be found here (http://learnlayout.com/percent.html) and also here (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp)